# Ansible : Newly created/old launch config not found for auto-scaling groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am working on an Ansible project in which I am creating a launch config. After that, I am trying to add it to an auto-scaling group. But it always says, launch config not found. what am I doing wrong? I can see in the AWS console, there is a launch config existing.

Error log :

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No launch config found with name Magento_Launch_Config"}
```

Code :

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
     - name: create launch config
       ec2_lc:
          name: Magento_Launch_Config
          image_id: "{{ ec2found.instances.0.image_id }}"
          region: eu-central-1
          security_groups: [ 'SG1', 'SG2']
          instance_type: c5n.large
          assign_public_ip: yes
       register: lc

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
     - name: Add auto-scaling groups.
       ec2_asg:
          name: magento_scaling_group
          load_balancers: [ 'magento_scaling_group' ]
          availability_zones: [ 'eu-central-1a', 'eu-central-1b', 'eu-central-1c' ]
          launch_config_name: "{{ lc.name }}"
          min_size: 1
          max_size: 5
          desired_capacity: 1
          vpc_zone_identifier: [ 'subnet-e712ad8c', 'subnet-e12e8dac', 'subnet-28e91a55' ]
          tags:
             - environment: test
               propagate_at_launch: no
```

Comment: Problem solved, I had to re-run aws configure on my localhost to change the region.

Comment: Or, the actual correct fix: to specify the region in the `ec2_asg:` just as you did for the `ec2_lc` module so your colleagues don't have to run `aws configure` like you did. Anyway, if you fixed this, please either add yourself as the answerer or close the question

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel : Please add ur answer, I will accept it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct fix is to use the `region:` attribute of the module for both, so the playbook runs independent of the local user's awscli configuration:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    aws_region: eu-central-1
  tasks:
     - name: create launch config
       ec2_lc:
          name: Magento_Launch_Config
          image_id: "{{ ec2found.instances.0.image_id }}"
          region: '{{ aws_region }}'
          security_groups: [ 'SG1', 'SG2']
          instance_type: c5n.large
          assign_public_ip: yes
       register: lc

     - name: Add auto-scaling groups.
       ec2_asg:
          name: magento_scaling_group
          load_balancers: [ 'magento_scaling_group' ]
          availability_zones: [ 'eu-central-1a', 'eu-central-1b', 'eu-central-1c' ]
          launch_config_name: "{{ lc.name }}"
          min_size: 1
          max_size: 5
          desired_capacity: 1
          region: '{{ aws_region }}'
          vpc_zone_identifier: [ 'subnet-e712ad8c', 'subnet-e12e8dac', 'subnet-28e91a55' ]
          tags:
             - environment: test
               propagate_at_launch: no
```